# Centering a multi-line block while keeping text aligned left

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, text, alignment

I tried various different  methods to no avail, including using `text-align: center;` on the `<div>` and `display: inline-block;` on the `<p>` and `<h4>`. Since the I have 3 different text tags inside the div I'm trying to align this only makes the text look centered and not aligned to the left.

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.media-body {text-align: center;}

p {display: inline-block}

h4 {display: inline-block;}
```

```html
<div id="j2" class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="block" class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
        <div class="media-body">
          <p id="time">10:00 A.M.</p>
          <h4 class="media-heading"><b>Meet & Greet</b></h4>
          <p>Nametags, Swag, Refreshments</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the usual solution:

```css
#block {
  text-align: center;
}
.media-body {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="block">
  <div class="media-body">
    <p id="time">10:00 A.M.</p>
    <h4 class="media-heading"><b>Meet & Greet</b></h4>
    <p>Nametags, Swag, Refreshments</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

But Bootstrap sets the property `width: 10000px;` to the `.media-body` class. Therefore, you need to redefine this property as `width: auto;`:

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

#block {
  text-align: center;
}
.media-body {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="j2" class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="block" class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
        <div class="media-body">
          <p id="time">10:00 A.M.</p>
          <h4 class="media-heading"><b>Meet & Greet</b></h4>
          <p>Nametags, Swag, Refreshments</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```